# What usage of if's is faster?

Tags: php

I am quite new to PHP, and I have a question about IF statements.

Example 1:

```
<?php
if($a == 1){
  if($b == 1){
    echo 'test';
  }
}
?>
```

Example 2:

```
<?php
if($a == 1 && $b ==1){
  echo 'test';
}
?>
```

Both have the same result, but which one is faster? Does it even matter?

Comment: If you ask "what is faster" you can usually test it yourself. Just make large number (hundreds of thousands, millions etc.) and measure time.

Comment: Ultimately, with minute things like this, readability is more important than any slight optimization.  Even if you were dealing with a large project that requires optimization, you could probably find it elsewhere, not with minor syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Premature Optimization & Micro Benchmark , you really need to read [Don't be STUPID: GRASP SOLID!](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html)  to understand why i said so

But if you want to know  `if($a == 1 && $b ==1)` seems faster is most PHP versions

[See Benchmark](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rYi85w)

If you want to know the real difference then look at the `opcodes`

First Code :

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~0      !0, 1
         1    > JMPZ                                                     ~0, ->7
   3     2  >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~1      !1, 1
         3    > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->6
   4     4  >   ECHO                                                     'test'
   5     5    > JMP                                                      ->6
   6     6  > > JMP                                                      ->7
         7  > > RETURN                                                   1
```

Secound Code

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~0      !0, 1
         1    > JMPZ_EX                                          ~0      ~0, ->4
         2  >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~1      !1, 1
         3      BOOL                                             ~0      ~1
         4  > > JMPZ                                                     ~0, ->7
   3     5  >   ECHO                                                     'test'
   4     6    > JMP                                                      ->7
         7  > > RETURN                                                   1
```

Can you see how similar with very minimal difference. And that is why it does not make sense to worry about this light this but write good and readable code.

Comment: I'm surprised that 5: JMP 6, 6: JMP 7 is not optimized.

Comment: @Voitcus tested in all PHP version and 90% of the time the second code was faster http://3v4l.org/JamIk

Comment: It's ok, I noticed something else: in the first code the line 5 is JMP to line 6 and in line 6 there is JMP to line 7; why is there line 6?

Answer (score 1):

They are the same - in both cases if the first condition is false, the second will not be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same. There are not much code to be optimized you can even write to make shorter syntax.

```
<?php
echo $a && b ? 'test' : '';
?>
```

Does the same.

I've modified a bit Baba's benchmark to check the results for shorthand syntax.

[Results](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4GdSt7)

Comment: Someone who downvoted may explain what's wrong with this post?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but this is not an answer to the question "which is faster".

Comment: So I can't explain this for somebody else.

Comment: Both will echo 'test' when $a and $b is true or 1 doesn't matter because it's not exact in that way.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter didn't consider it to be the same because you did not do `$a==1 && $b==1`.  Just a guess.

Comment: Doesn't matter for me if someone doesn't see difference between `==` and `===`. Easier/faster to downvoted than check if it's correct.

Comment: The problem with that logic is, in PHP, 0 is false and any other integer is true (whether it's 1, 5, -200).  [Documentation behind this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) in case anyone comes across this post later.

Answer (score 1):

Preoptimization is the root to all evil.

That said, your first piece of code is a tiny bit faster (but again, minimally - don't bother to change your code to this - **readability is way more important than the tiny speed incremention you get from changing your conditions**.

[3,000,000 iterations of the first piece of code](http://codepad.org/J1g9Xo9x): ~ 0.9861679077 seconds
[3,000,000 iterations of the second piece of code](http://codepad.org/LaVfiftS): ~ 1.0684559345 seconds

Difference: ~ 0.0822880268 seconds
Difference per iteration: ~ 0.0000000274 seconds (or 274 nano seconds).

Comment: That is why I like shorthand syntax :)

Comment: Thanks not how to benchmark a code .... they are running on separate instance ....

Comment: @Baba Obviously you don't want to run them after eachother, as the PHP compiler won't have GC'd at the time, hence the last piece of code will always be a tiny bit more slow than it should be. Feel free to prove me wrong in the benchmark. That said, it surprised me as well, as I was expecting the second piece of code to be a tiny bit faster. No matter if it's seperate instances you'll notice that the second piece of code usually lies about ~ 1.08 on codepad, and the second one from ~ 0.98 - ~ 1.06. It might be codepad's PHP version (5.2.5).

Comment: I performed the same benchmark:
[First Code](http://codepad.org/jt7v9i77) ~1.4979648590 seconds, 
[Second Code](http://codepad.org/LaVfiftS) ~1.0870530605 seconds.  My results are the opposite.  I don't feel it's a fair comparison because this code is being run on a shared server.

Comment: first -- Time taken: 1.0870530605 seconds, second -- Time taken: 1.0447418690 seconds.

Comment: @sectus The output seems to be cached. I accidentally had switched around the links so the results are opposite.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not matter. Such little performance tweaks are usually overcome by the running environment. Such as inefficient algorithms or client side best practices being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same, because PHP interpreter is "smart enough" to figure out that.

Comment: use cases:
1. a == 1 b == 1 - both conditions will be tested
2. a == 1 b == x - first will be tested, second will fail
3. a == 2 b == x - first will be tested and that is end of condition b will not be taken into consideration